# 3n+1 Program for Online Judge

Tags: c

I have written a program to solve the 3n+1 problem ([Collatz Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture)) in Online Judge. I have noticed the important issues such as, the first input may be smaller than the second input, etc.

But I always get notification of wrong answers when it is judged online. Could you please help me see where I make mistakes. Thanks.

The following is my program. Note that I use a array for storing the cycle of traversed number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int maxcyc = 0;
    int curcyc;
    int i, min, max;
    unsigned long n;
    int *cach = (int *)malloc(1000000 * sizeof(int));
    if (cach == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory Allocation Error\n");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
    {
        cach[i] = 0;
    }
    if (scanf("%d  %d", &min, &max) == 2)
    {
        printf("%d %d ", min, max);
        if (min > max)
        {
            min = min ^ max;
            max = max ^ min;
            min = min ^ max;
        }
        for (i = min; i < max + 1; ++i)
        {
            curcyc = 1;
            n = i;
            while (n != 1)
            {
                if (n < 1000000 && cach[n])
                {
                    curcyc = curcyc + cach[n] - 1;
                    break;
                }
                curcyc++;
                if (n & 0x0001)
                {
                    if (n >= ULONG_MAX / 3)
                    {
                        printf("%d overflow at step %d\n", i, curcyc);
                    }
                    n = 3 * n + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    n = n >> 1;
                }
            }
            cach[i] = curcyc;
            maxcyc = maxcyc > curcyc ? maxcyc : curcyc;
        }
        printf("%d\n", maxcyc);
    }
    free(cach);
    return 0;
}
```

PS: a detailed description and instruction of this problem can be referred at http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=3&page=show_problem&problem=36

I have updated the code by changing the type of n to `unsigned long` and added a `if` statement to expectedly check overflow leading by 3 * n + 1. But there still exists error in this program, not passing the judgement. Still Need Help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post example of how input/output should look like?

Comment: This is collatz sequence, the input will probably consist of `n` number of tests, followed by n numbers which you have to run the sequence on

Comment: I think the interesting question is what the output should be. My guess is that the line `curcyc = curcyc + cach[n] - 1;` is wrong, but since I have no idea what it is supposed to calculate, it is hard to say.

Comment: @user2699298 For example, if I input "i j", the program outputs "i j k" in output, where k is the maximum cycle lengths for integers between i and j. A more detailed instruction can be referred at http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=3&page=show_problem&problem=37

Comment: Can I deduct a point for lack of indentation.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig But I still have correct output for all my tests using this line.

Comment: Why not write `n /= 2;` instead of using the shift operator? The compiler will probably optimize anyway if it is safe to do so.  (You could write `n >>= 1;` if you wanted to, but using the shift is not really necessary and the Collatz algorithm is defined in terms of multiply-and-add and divide without mentioning anything shifty.)  The swap using xor `^` is also modestly ridiculous.

Comment: What have you done for debugging? Have you printed out the answer you get for the length of each value, and checked that the value is correct (say, for range 20-30). You might want to delay hand-calculating for 27, but the values should be: `o = 20 m = 20 c = 7`, 
`o = 21 m = 64 c = 7`,
`o = 22 m = 52 c = 15`,
`o = 23 m = 160 c = 15`,
`o = 24 m = 24 c = 10`,
`o = 25 m = 88 c = 23`,
`o = 26 m = 40 c = 10`,
`o = 27 m = 9232 c = 111`,
`o = 28 m = 52 c = 18`,
`o = 29 m = 88 c = 18`,
`o = 30 m = 160 c = 18`.  In each group, `o` is the input value, `m` is the maximum value, and `c` is the length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm moderately confident this works.  It produces the same answers as the brute force `bc` program I alluded to in comments up to 1 million (at least, once I'd modified the `bc` program to count the number of values in the chain rather than the number of transitions).  It is very fast up to 1 million.  It slows as the cache becomes less effective at 10 million and 100 million.

Sample outputs (code compiled with `-DPRODUCTION`):

```
$ j=10; for i in 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; do j="$j$i"; ./collatz-so <<< "2 $j"; done
2 100 119
2 1000 179
2 10000 262
2 100000 351
2 1000000 525
2 10000000 686
2 100000000 950
$
```

Sample output with code compiled for debug:

```
$ ./collatz-so <<< '1 30'
   1:    1
   2:    2
   3:    8
   4:    3
   5:    6
   6:    9
   7:   17
   8:    4
   9:   20
  10:    7
  11:   15
  12:   10
  13:   10
  14:   18
  15:   18
  16:    5
  17:   13
  18:   21
  19:   21
  20:    8
  21:    8
  22:   16
  23:   16
  24:   11
  25:   24
  26:   11
  27:  112
  28:   19
  29:   19
  30:   19
1 30 112
$
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#if defined(PRODUCTION)
#define DEBUG 0
#else
#define DEBUG 1
#endif

static const int debug = DEBUG;

enum { CACHE_SIZE = 1000000 };

int main(void)
{
  int maxcyc = 0;
  int curcyc;
  int i, min, max;
  unsigned long n;
  int *cache = (int *)calloc(CACHE_SIZE, sizeof(int));
  if (cache == NULL)
  {
    printf("Memory Allocation Error\n");
    return 1;
  }

  if (scanf("%d %d", &min, &max) == 2)
  {
    if (min > max)
    {
      min = min ^ max;
      max = max ^ min;
      min = min ^ max;
    }
    for (i = min; i < max + 1; ++i)
    {
      curcyc = 1;
      n = i;
      while (n != 1)
      {
        if (n < CACHE_SIZE && cache[n])
        {
          //printf("%lu: cache[%lu] = %d; c = %d\n", n, n, cache[n], curcyc);
          curcyc += cache[n] - 1;
          break;
        }
        curcyc++;
        if (n & 0x0001)
          n = 3 * n + 1;
        else
          n /= 2;
      }
      if (i < CACHE_SIZE)
      {
        cache[i] = curcyc;
        //printf("cache[%d] = %d\n", i, curcyc);
      }
      if (debug)
        printf("%4d: %4d\n", i, curcyc);
      maxcyc = maxcyc > curcyc ? maxcyc : curcyc;
    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n", min, max, maxcyc);
  }

  free(cache);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start curcyc at 0 instead of 1 and don't subtract from the cached value.  Your algorithm is wrong because of this.

Also, n might be overflowing during the execution of the algorithm depending on the starting value.

Comment: I do not think so. You can see the example of 3n+1 problem in [link](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=3&page=show_problem&problem=36). The cycle of 1 has also been counted.

Comment: n should not be overflowing I think. I have set it as unsigned int. When I run with the input 1 999999, the program can correctly returns 1 999999 525.

Comment: It is pure fluke that you end up with the correct answer; your code generates off-by-one answers for the range 20-30. This answer does, very cryptically, tell you what needs fixing. You definitely get overflow of 32-bit values (input 704511 goes up to 56,991,483,520 in 242 steps; input 837799 only goes up to 2,974,984,576 in 524 steps). If you're convinced that the input 2 takes 2 steps, then you can use 525, but I think you normally say 2 takes 1 step to get to 1.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you very much. I have found that my program actually overflows when the input is 704511 and 837799. I have changed the type of n to unsigned long. But I am still notified wrong answer (maybe overflow at other inputs? how can I check this?). I am convinced that the input 2 takes 2 steps because in the example of 3n+1 problem instruction, it says the cycle length of 22 is 16. The step at 1 is also counted.

Comment: OK; they want the number of values in the sequence rather than the count of the operations needed to get to 1. If you're on a 64-bit Unix system, then `unsigned long` should be OK (for some distance beyond 1,000,000 anyway).  If you're on a 32-bit machine or Windows 64-bit, you need to go to a 64-bit type; the standard one would be `unsigned long long`.  I have a program written in `bc` to do the calculation (fast it is not, but accurate it is). It took a three and a half minutes to calculate all the values up to one million, but does not use caching to speed up the brute force calculations.